# What will be the regex that not accept 0-0-0?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write regex that can accept the following points,

1-The format should be x-y-z

2-x,y and z should be numbers.

3- x can be any number.

4-y can not be exceeded from 20.

5. z can not be exceeded from 272.

6- x,y,z can not be 0 at the same time.

I wrote a regex that fulfilled the first 5 points. The regex is

```
^([0-9]+)-([0-9]|1[0-9])-([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-6][0-9]|27[0-2])$
```

But it also accept the 0-0-0 which should not be accepted. Is there any way to avoid 0-0-0?

Comment: What is the regex flavor? Java? Python? Or Bash?

Comment: What do you mean by regex flavor?

Comment: If your regex flavor supports lookaheads, use `^(?!0+-0+-0+$)([0-9]+)-([0-9]|1[0-9])-([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-6][0-9]|27[0-2])$`

Comment: Flavor is the kind of a regex your environment supports. Where do you use the regex?

Comment: In javascript. BTW it works. Thanks buddy. Yoy can post it as a answer so that i mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: This is the kind of problem you maybe shouldn't solve using regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `(?!0+-0+-0+$)` negative lookahead at the start right after the `^` to anchor it:

```
^(?!0+-0+-0+$)([0-9]+)-([0-9]|1[0-9])-([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-6][0-9]‌​|27[0-2])$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nM9xI7/1)

The `(?!0+-0+-0+$)` will fail a match if the whole string only contains `0`s and `-`s.

```js
var re = /^(?!0+-0+-0+$)([0-9]+)-([0-9]|1[0-9])-([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-6][0-9]‌​|27[0-2])$/; 
var strs = ['1-19-44', '0-0-0', '0-0-6'];
for (var s of strs) {
  document.body.innerHTML += s + ": <b>" + re.test(s) + "</b><br/>";
}
```